# Imagem de todas categoria no post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu tenho algumas categorias e nessas categorias tenho imagens.

Digamos que eu tenha o `post1` e nesse `post1` tenho a `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3`. Quando entro no post no modo "*single_post*" é exibido apenas a imagem da `cat1`, porém, gostaria que mostrasse as 3 imagens, uma ao lado da outra. Isso é possível?

Esse é o script que mostra a *Thumb* da categoria do *post*:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('sydney-large-thumb'); ?>
```

Comment: Como você esta inserindo as imagens nas categorias? `the_post_thumbnail` busca imagens anexadas à tabela `wp_postmeta`, então elas não podem estar associadas a uma categoria e sim ao post. Confira como as imagens das categorias estao sendo salvas (qual função é chamada, ou como elas aparecem no banco) e ai dá pra resolver.

Comment: Ricardo as imagens estão sendo anexadas na categoria por intermédio de um plugin.. esse script acima é do próprio template.

Comment: Exato. O padrao de templates é mostrar a imagem do post. O plugin está salvando essas imagens em outro lugar do banco. (pode ser uma coincidência que a imagem de cat1 e post1 seja a mesma). O que a gente precisa saber é como o plugin faz isso, ai da pra modificar.

Comment: Eu não inserindo imagem no post, existe um plugin que por padrão determina as imagens na categoria, o post fica sem qualquer imagem.

Comment: Estou usando o plugin Category Featured Images - Extended. Ele termina a imagem da categoria, porem se tiver 1 categoria com imagem e você adicionar outra categoria também com imagem ele faz a troca de imagens pela ultima categoria colocada.

Comment: Dei uma olhada rápida no codigo do plugin. Ele não tem essa previsão de usar mais de uma imagem - que ele faz é interceptar a chamada pro banco que buscaria o thumbnail do post e direcionar pra imagem de uma categoria. Um desenvolvedor pode alterar isso pra você, mas é um escopo grande demais pra uma resposta aqui.

Comment: Entendo, mesmo assim grato pela sua atenção.